# Simple inheritance issue with Django templates

Tags: python, django, for-loop, inheritance

just getting started in Django, and I have some problems with the inheritances. It just seems that the loop for doesn't work when inheriting other template. Here's my code in base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}Titulo del proyecto web{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Título del proyecto web</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So here in the index.html the objective is to show the for loop and also the 'header' div of base. Index.html is this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Questions{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for pregunta in preguntas %}
    <h3>{{ pregunta }} ?</h3><br/>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I've checked the code several times. If I quit the inheritance the loop works fine, but I don't know why it doesn't work when extending to base.html.

When I run the server page it just appears a blank page. Help would be highly appreciate. Thank you very much.

EDIT: Here it is my template directories structure:

Main Project/Templates/ and inside Templates folder there's the base.html and a 'preguntasyrespuestas' folder which is the app name.

And inside 'preguntasyrespuestas' folder there is the index.html template. But it automatically creates a 'base.html' also inside this folder (?) I just delete it.

And the views.py code is that shown here:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
from preguntasyrespuestas.models import Pregunta
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response

def index(request):
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('preguntasyrespuestas/index.html',
                                        {'preguntas': preguntas})

def pregunta_detalle(request, pregunta_id):
    pregunta = get_object_or_404(Pregunta, pk=pregunta_id)
    return render_to_response('preguntasyrespuestas/pregunta_detalle.html',
                                        {'pregunta': pregunta})
```

Here's the settings.py template var:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["C:/Projects/primerproyecto/Templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So, must both files (base.html and index.html) be in the Templates directory (not inside the app directory inside templates)? I've tried it and still happens the same (output a blank page), if not an error while trying to combine files locations (between theses two folders).

Comment: You need to 
show your view.

Comment: You have to show your template folder structure and content.

Comment: Django doesn't automatically create base.html files. But which view are you going to (and why did you post the other one)?

Comment: I tried with {{ pregunta.asunto }} (which is a field of it) and it still doesn't show any result. 

The thing is that without the heritances the loop showed well, just can't figure why not now.

Comment: @Jim, showing a blank page could means the error came from somewhere else. You may be debugging at the wrong place? or perhaps it is the browser cache? but to answer your simple question, all template files must be made available in any of the locations which the template `LOADERS` can find it, both files can be place across different templates location. by default, there will only be 2 loaders, the filesystem, which is template `DIRS` and the app template, `/<project>/<app>/templates/*`, you can mix any of the location, as long as it can be found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your app the template folder structure must be something like:

```
|- preguntasyrespuestas # your app folder
    |- templates
       -base.html
       |- preguntasyrespuestas
          -index.html
          -pregunta_detalle.html
          ....
```

Templates directory must be in your app folder and inside it must be another folder with the name of your app and inside this must be the template files.

**EDIT**

If your templates are in the app template folder you should change `DIRS` to an empty list: `DIRS:[]`

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [], # change here: put an empty list
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Hey, i've just tried and it is still happening the same. Should I change settings.py route then? It doesn't work anyway

Comment: Hey, it I ran it again and it was a problem of the editor and the route changes, just ran it again and now it works!! Should I consider anything while keep doing the project with these Template changes? (even the settings route or the folder location change). THANK YOU very much!