# URL issue in Django template

Tags: python, django, templates, url

This question is quite related to [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137279/simple-inheritance-issue-with-django-templates/).

I've seen that working with Templates creates some Django version problem with a tutorial I'm following, I think there's something wrong with the urls. Here's my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^preguntas/$', 'preguntasyrespuestas.views.index', name='preguntas'),
url(r'^preguntas/(?P<pregunta_id>\d+)/$', 'preguntasyrespuestas.views.pregunta_detalle', name='pregunta_detalle')
)
```

And the link isn't working is in that index.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Questions{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% for pregunta in preguntas %}
<a href="(% url "pregunta_detalle" pregunta.id %}">{{ pregunta.asunto }} ?</a><br/>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also, here are my views.py:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse,Http404
 from preguntasyrespuestas.models import Pregunta
 from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response

 def index(request):
     preguntas = Pregunta.objects.all()
     return render_to_response('preguntasyrespuestas/index.html',
                                    {'preguntas': preguntas})

 def pregunta_detalle(request, pregunta_id):
     pregunta = get_object_or_404(Pregunta, pk=pregunta_id)
     return render_to_response('preguntasyrespuestas/pregunta_detalle.html',
                                    {'pregunta': pregunta})
```

The error reported by the browser says something like:

```
 Using the URLconf defined in primerproyecto.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
 ^preguntas/$ [name='preguntas']
 ^preguntas/(?P<pregunta_id>\d+)/$ [name='pregunta_detalle']
 The current URL, preguntas/(% url, didn't match any of these.
```

Instead, if I type the URL in the browser '127.0.0.0.1:8000/preguntas/1' it appears. What kind of URL connection could be wrong? Can't find the answer... really appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 2):

It should work if you use single quotation marks around the URL name. You also need to alter the opening bracket in your `href` to a curly-brace `{`:

```
<a href="{% url 'pregunta_detalle' pregunta.id %}">{{ pregunta.asunto }} ?</a>
         ^      ^                ^
```

Comment: You don't actually need to change the quotes there; since the HTML tag and template tag are in different contexts, they don't get confused.

Comment: Interesting - I didn't realise. Thanks for the tip.